# Move redirection instructions to variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to store redirection instructions in a variable? Something along these lines:

```
set redirect=>> buildlog.txt 2>&1

nmake -f Makefile %redirect%
```

As is, this doesn't work.

Comment: you'd have to enclose the var assignment in quotes, because otherwise the redirect gets applied to the `set` command, isntead of the characters `2`, `>`, etc... getting assigned as text to the variable.

Comment: @MarcB Can you provide a working example? I've tried with quotes but it doesn't work either...

Comment: I am not quite understanding what you want in your buildlog.txt file.  Do you want buildlog.txt to contain **set redirect=** ?

Comment: @Squashman Nope, I want it to contain the output of `nmake`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `>` are shell metachars, you can't directly use them to assign to a variable a text. They'll get executed by the shell and their RESULT gets assigned. So you have to quote/escape them:

```
set redirect=^>^>buildlog.txt 2^>^&1
             ^-^--etc... cmd uses ^ to escape.
```

Which then works as you expect:

```
C:\temp\z>set foo=^>^>log.txt
C:\temp\z>dir %foo%
C:\temp\z>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0E31-0E35

 Directory of C:\temp\z

09/23/2016  10:32 AM    <DIR>          .
09/23/2016  10:32 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/23/2016  10:32 AM               333 log.txt
               1 File(s)            333 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  274,917,388,288 bytes free

C:\temp\z>type log.txt
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0E31-0E35

 Directory of C:\temp\z

09/23/2016  10:32 AM    <DIR>          .
09/23/2016  10:32 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/23/2016  10:32 AM                 0 log.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  274,917,388,288 bytes free
```

Comment: `set "redirect=>> buildlog.txt 2>&1"` (quoting avoids need of escaping...)

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is use delayed expansion.

```
 @echo off
 set "redirect=>> buildlog.txt 2>&1"

 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 nmake -f Makefile !redirect!
 endlocal
```

Comment: No, this does not work. Once you properly get the `>` and `&` in the variable, you must use `%redirect%` if you want the redirection to function.